# Java/Spring-boot/Mockito @MockBean annotation work strange

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

In tests i mock DateService to have the same date every time when i run the test, but when i use DateServie in other service then the mock retun null all the time. It is strange because the mock works in my custom date time provder. Here is the code:

Its work here:

```
@Service(MyDateTimeProvider.MY_DATE_TIME_PROVIDER)
public class MyDateTimeProvider implements DateTimeProvider {

    public static final String MY_DATE_TIME_PROVIDER = "MyDateTimeProvider";

    @Autowired
    private DateService dateService;

    @Override
    public Optional<TemporalAccessor> getNow() {
        return Optional.of(dateService.getCurrentDate().toInstant());
    }

}


@Service
public class DateService {

    public Date getCurrentDate() {
        return new Date();
    }

}
```

Its not work in the UserService:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class Test{

    @MockBean
    protected DateService dateService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {  Mockito.when(dateService.getCurrentDate()).thenReturn(DEFAULT_DATE_TIME.toDate());
    }

...
}


@Service
public class UserService {
  
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private DateService dateService;
  
    private User createNewUser(final UserDto dto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
        user.setRegistrationDate(dateService.getCurrentDate()); // i got null here
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

What did i wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a test code, please? Where do you get a null value?

Comment: Which version of Junit are you using? Spring Boot version?

Comment: Junit5 and 2.3.10.RELEASE

Comment: Note that `Clock` exists for this specific case, and it's considered appropriate to use `Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC()` and have a setter.

Comment: Can you please also add all `import` sections? Maybe there's mix between JUnit 4 and JUnit 5.

Comment: i only use junit5.   junit4 is excluded in pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague helped me. My problem was: i used "UserService" in a method with @PostConstuct annotation, so its run before the mock happened.