# Creating a DateTimeProvider bean for mocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, jpa, mocking

I need to write some tests for a JPA service that is creating/updating an entity. In order to properly test the 'createDate' field, I need to mock the DateTimeProvider that JPA is using so that I can test against a fixed date. I found a partial answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63530418/1860222 but they don't provide any details on HOW to define the testDateTimeProvider bean. I found another post that looked close to what I needed ([Java/Spring-boot/Mockito @MockBean annotation work strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991672/java-spring-boot-mockito-mockbean-annotation-work-strange)), but so far I have not been able to get that working either.

I created a Service class like this:

```
@Service("testDateTimeProvider")
public class TestDateTimeProvider implements DateTimeProvider {
    
    public TestDateTimeProvider() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current time to be used as modification or creation date.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<TemporalAccessor> getNow() {
        return Optional.of(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2023-09-22T17:00:00.00Z"), ZoneId.of("UTC"))));
    }
}
```

In my tests I have a class like:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DatabaseSetup("data.xml")
@DatabaseTearDown("data.xml")
@Import({TestDateTimeProvider.class})
@EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "testDateTimeProvider")
public class MessageServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private Clock clock;
    
    @Autowired
    MessagesService messagesService;

    @MockBean
    private DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;

    @Test
    public void testSaveNewMessage()
    {
        LocalDateTime expectedCreate = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
        Mockito.when( dateTimeProvider.getNow()).thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedCreate));
        Message actual = messagesService.saveMessage("abc", 123);
        assertNotNull(actual);
        assertThat(actual.getCreateDate()).isEqualToIgnoringNanos(expectedCreate);
    }
}
```

If I run that test, it will fail while setting up the mock. Stepping through the code, I can see that 'dateTimeProvider' never gets injected, so a null pointer exception will be thrown when calling 'dateTimeProvider.now'.

I'm a bit new to spring so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Why is my MockBean not getting injected? Is this even the correct approach for mocking creation timestamps?

Comment: How and where is `messagesService` created? I would expect to see it declared as a field in the test with an `@InjectMocks` annotation, but instead I don't see it declared in this code at all?

Comment: @DavidConrad It isn't really relevant to this example since the test is erroring out before it ever gets to the service call. I will update the example to include the service injection for the sake of clarity however.

Comment: Injecting it with `@Autowired` means you'll get one created by Spring with all the normal dependencies, not any mock dependencies.

Comment: @DavidConrad Right. The MessagesService isn't the problem here. It is the DateTimeProvider that I need to mock.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure out the problem. I was using hibernate @CreationTimestamp in my entity class to annotate the createdDate field. All the examples I have been looking at use JPA @CreatedDate instead. I found a more complete example here: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/mocking-spring-data-datetimeprovider/ that gave me enough information to get things working.

That said, I'm still curious if anyone knows if a good solution to this problem for the hibernate specific annotations. I will leave the question open for now.